# Best recaptcha library for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

What is the best recaptcha library for Rails 3?

I found three projects:
[ruby recaptcha](http://bitbucket.org/mml/ruby-recaptcha/wiki/Home),
[rack recaptcha](http://github.com/achiu/rack-recaptcha),
[recaptcha](http://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that [rack recaptcha](http://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/) is the best for me.

Comment: rack recaptcha looks very promising!

Comment: That link does not go to rack-recaptcha: https://github.com/achiu/rack-recaptcha.  Did you use the wrong url or did you prefer ambethia's recaptcha.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you like this: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_captcha.html

Answer (score 2):

I use this one in one of my rails 3 project and it's works like a charm

```
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rfc2822/recaptcha.git', :branch => 'rails3'
```